# SwiftUI iOS 13 ZStack isn't behave the same as in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My code is very simple:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text("hello")
            ZStack(alignment: .leading, content: {

                Color(.white)
            })
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 2, x: 0, y: 0)
            .padding()
        }

    }
}
```

In iOS 14:
[image]

In iOS 13:
[image]

How could I make iOS 13 the same as iOS 14? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("hello")
            ZStack(alignment: .leading, content: {
                
                Color(.white)
                    .frame(maxHeight:.infinity)
            })
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 2, x: 0, y: 0)
            .padding()
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you do not need play with frame, simply use this code:

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("hello")
            
            ZStack(alignment: .leading, content: {
                
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.white)

                
            })
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 2, x: 0, y: 0)
            .padding()
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accept answer works.
But my solution is familiar:

```
 ZStack(alignment: .leading, content: {

                Color(.white)
            })
.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
```

Because I have many parts use `ZStack` and for `ZStack` I can add a modifier instead of adding to every places.so I also provide my own solutions here.